# Totien-Sum: why GCD( {n}/d, q/d) = 1; implies Sum{Totient(d/q) } = q

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, galois-theory, finite-fields

Have seen answer to this question. still don't understand..

Totient sum is defined:     q = Sum(Totient (d) ); sum on all d : d|q

More specific; The proof has these steps:
  1.    If d is a divider of q so is q/d.
  2.    If GCD([n1, n2, ..], q) = [d d, .., d] then
        GCD([n1, n2, ..]/d,  q/d) = [1, 1,.. 1];
  3.    Sum{ Totient(d) }  =  Sum{Totient(q/d) } = q;
        The sum is over all the set d - dividers of q

1, 2, above are fairly simple. However i failed to understand why 2. implies 3

Answer (score 0):

The set {n}/d - that is to say, the set {n} divided  by its GCD d - is co-prime to q/n. It is the complete set (other wise it implies that {n} is not complete). 
By definition, totient(q/d) counts the number of co-primes to q/d

Since 1:q are partitioned into non overlapped groups the sum(totient({q/d) ) = q.

Answer (score 0):

On The Euler (Totient) Function Multiplicity

Define theTotient function as Eu(.). To prove Eu(N∙M) = Eu(N)∙Eu(M). The set 1:N∙M is partitioned  into set of columns. Each column is a sum of a base column:   C0 = [ 0, M, ..  (N-1)M]’;
and an offset - k;        k: 1,2,..M; 
A column Ck is:                       Ck= C0 + k.

An element of a column Ck  is the sum: s =  nM + k.  Columns are different by their offset k only. 
The following lemma is used: For a, b and c natural numbers greater than zero we have:
If c = a + b; then: GCD(a, b) = GCD(a, c) = GCD(b,c);

Therefore It is sufficient that the offset k  alone be “free” of any divider d > 1 - that divides M -  to guarantee that the entire column Ck doesn’t have d as a divider.

Next: How many elements in the selected columns  fulfill: GCD(Ck, N) == 1?.

To this end the  following is proposed:
a.  Cr  = rem(Ck,  N);  rem(.) is the remainder modulo N. Cr(.) is a column of remainders
b.  CrM     = GCD(Cr, N) == 1;  Crm is a mask of zeros column with one at
n: GCD(Cr(n), N) =1;
c.  Number of elements{ GCD(Ck,N) == 1 } = Sum(CrM) ;

In step a. an element Ck(n) is written: Ck(n) = N∙q(n) + Cr(n); we know (Euclid GCD algorithm): 
GCD(Ck(n), N) = GCD(Cr(n), N);

Recall that a column Ck is:
Ck = C0 + k = (0:N-1)’∙M + k; k = 1:M; 
The Modulo N operation transforms the column Ck into the elements 1:N. Note that gcd(N, M) =1. therefore rem(C0, N) is the set: 0:N-1 with No repetition. Only the order is permutated depends on the value of the offset k.

Consequently: Sum(CrM)  = Eu(N); is identical to all columns.

Eu(N)∙Eu(M) = (elements in Ck: GCD(Ck,N) =1) x (number of column: GCD(Ck, M)=1) = total elements in 1:NM that don’t divide NM.
Therefore: Eu(N)∙Eu(M) = Eu(NM);

Comment: Your Answer would be easier to read if formatted with [mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$.  Subscripts and superscripts are particularly easy to create.